# Photo comment plugin

Tags: plugin-recommendation

I'm searching for a plugin that is (for all logged-in persons of a group) showing one picture of a member/gallery and allow them to leave a short comment on this. Users shouldn't see comments posted by others and once they have seen a picture it shouldn't be shown again. They should also be allowed to skip a picture.

Is there some plugin that is doing something near to that? I don't mind coding and changing it for my needs, so any plugin that is doing at least some parts of it is appreciated.

Thank you!´in advance!

Answer (score 1):

You can use the built-in Wordpress attachments to accomplish this. You can add a template file called image.php to your theme. The best place to start is open the Twenty Eleven theme and look at the file named image.php. It has all of the code you need to get started.

I would then use the standard Wordpress gallery embedded in a post with links to the image's attachment page rather than links to the files themselves.